# rotate image around fixed point

Tags: image-processing, geometric-transform

How can I painlessly rotate a tiff image by some small angle around a point with specific coordinates? The image shouldn't be altered otherwise, it can be padded with zeros if necessary, and then saved back into tiff format. It should also output the coordinates of the center of rotation on a new image.

I see `ImageRotate` function but it doesn't allow to specify the point of rotation.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show an example input and two example outputs for two different centers of rotation.  I can't see how a "center of rotation" makes any difference when you need to pad the image anyway.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to combine `ImageTransformation` and `RotationTransform` (where you can specify a center).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you might want to work with `ImageTransformation`

```
ImageTransformation[ img ,
 RotationTransform[ .2 , {.75, .5} ] , 
 PlotRange -> {{-1/2, 3/2}, {-1/2, 3/2}}, Background -> White, 
 Masking -> All]
```

[image]

animation of rotation about a point near the edge..

[image]